# Does Android force a destroy of a Service after 1 minute if the controlling application is running in background?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service, background-process

It seems if I start a Service from an app but do not call startForeground() in the onStartCommand method, and I then put the app in background, after one minute the onDestroy callback is called and the Service is destroyed.

I have not seen this stated anywhere in the Android documentation.  Rather, the documentation says vaguely that eventually this kind of Service will be destroyed.

Notice that the onStartCommand method returns START_STICKY.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Code for the Service follows; it is meant to explore the Service capability, not as an actual production app.  Also, programming sometimes does the same thing different ways; I have been trying different approaches to get more insight.  And I am pretty new to Android; regret naively written code.

```
class IntegerCounting : Service() {
    companion object {
        var theCounter : Int = 0
    }
    private lateinit var mHandler: Handler
    private lateinit var mRunnable: Runnable

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        throw UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        // Send a notification that service is started
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service started.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        // Do a periodic task
        mHandler = Handler()
        mRunnable = Runnable { CountByOne() }
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 500)

        return Service.START_STICKY
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service destroyed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable)
    }

    override fun onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent?) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "On Task Removed called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    // Custom method to do a task
    private fun CountByOne() {
        ++theCounter
        if (theCounter % 10 == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "count by one " + theCounter.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        //showSomeText(theCounter.toString())
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 500)
    }
}
```

The MainActivity class follows:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    // Here is how you find out if an Android service is running
    private fun isServiceRunning(serviceClass: Class<*>): Boolean {
        val activityManager = getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager

        // Loop through the running services
        for (service in activityManager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.name == service.service.className) {
                // If the service is running then return true
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Variable to hold service class name
        val serviceClass = IntegerCounting::class.java

        // Notice the service class is defined here, so subsequently all
        // we need to access this service is this instance of Intent
        val intent = Intent(applicationContext, serviceClass)

        counterText = findViewById(R.id.counter)
        counterText.text = "Ready to start counting"

        val startButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.start_counting)
        val stopButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.stop_counting)
        val showStatus: Button = findViewById(R.id.show_status)

        startButton.setOnClickListener({
            if (!isServiceRunning(serviceClass)) {
                counterText.text = "Starting Integer Counter service"
                startService(intent)
            } else {
                counterText.text = "Integer Counter service already running"
            }
        })

        stopButton.setOnClickListener {
            if (isServiceRunning(serviceClass)) {
                counterText.text = "Stopping Integer Counter service"
                stopService(intent)
            } else {
                counterText.text = "Integer Counter service already stopped"
            }
        }

        showStatus.setOnClickListener({
            if (isServiceRunning(serviceClass)) {
                counterText.text = "Integer Counter service is running, counter: " +
                                    IntegerCounting.theCounter.toString()
            } else {
                counterText.text = "Integer Counter service is stopped, counter " +
                                    IntegerCounting.theCounter.toString()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your app target larger than android O it's normal behaviors when your app go background. To keeping `Service` try to use `startForceground` with `Notification`

> While an app is in the foreground, it can create and run both foreground and background services freely. When an app goes into the background, it has a window of several minutes in which it is still allowed to create and use services. At the end of that window, the app is considered to be idle. At this time, the system stops the app's background services, just as if the app had called the services' Service.stopSelf() methods.

Documents [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Công Hải.  I had kind of come to the conclusion I needed to call startForeground to keep this service around indefinitely.  One minor point point: the documentation you linked to implies the service associated with background app has "a window of several minutes", but my work shows that window is right about 1 minute.  Thanks again for the clarification!